# CSF Blocking IP on Fail POP3 and cPanel

Tags: csf

I have a VPS with cPanel and i am running around 400+ email accounts under a Office Network, I don't have STATIC IP but i am facing issue when any 1 of employee forget the password and try to access it too many times so cPanel Blocks the IP and entire Network is unable to get / sent mails due to that employee..

This could have been very easy if I have a STATIC IP and i can put into WhiteList. Currently i have turn the firewall off due to this. Any tips or suggestion would be great

Answer (score 1):

You should white list the subnet that the public dynamic in belongs to.   Often your is will change but remain in the same subnet.

I would look up the subnet mask of the public dynamic in and then using a subnet calculator find the network I'd and the CIDR notation for the subnet.   You can then white list the subnet with the CIDR notation.

For example if your public is was 100.1.1.95 and your subnet was 255.255.255.0 the CIDR notation of the subnet would be 24.

The network id (the first is on the subnet) would be 10.1.1.1 so you would white list the in followed by a slash and cider notation.   In this case it would be 10.1.1.1/24

Hope this helps!